# Understanding akka actor default behavior on crash

Tags: scala, akka

The default behavior of actor is restart.
In order to get better understanding, I created two actors and a crash to cause the restart:

```
class PingActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import PingActor._
  override def postRestart(reason: Throwable): Unit = {
    log.info(s"RESTARTING")
    super.postRestart(reason)
  }
  var counter = 0
  val pongActor = context.actorOf(PongActor.props, "pongActor")
  def receive = {
    case Initialize => 
      pongActor ! PingMessage("ping")   
    case PongActor.PongMessage(text) =>
      log.info("In PingActor - received message: {}", text)
      counter += 1
      if (counter == 3) {
         log.info("FIN")
        context.system.shutdown()
      }
      if (counter == 2) {
        sender() ! PingMessage("ping")
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Aooch")

      }
      else sender() ! PingMessage("ping")
  } 
}
object PingActor {
  val props = Props[PingActor]
  case object Initialize
  case class PingMessage(text: String)
}

class PongActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import PongActor._
  def receive = {
    case PingActor.PingMessage(text) => 
      log.info("In PongActor - received message: {}", text)
      sender() ! PongMessage("pong")
  }
}

object PongActor {
  val props = Props[PongActor]
  case class PongMessage(text: String)
}
```

so the `PingActor` is sending the message before the crash and `PongActor` replies when the Ping actor restarts it accepts the message but the sender (`PongActor`) is not available. I do see this line in deadLetters

> [INFO] [MyActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]
>   [akka://MyActorSystem/user/pingActor/pongActor] Message
>   [com.example.PingActor$PingMessage] from
>   Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/user/pingActor#-1362690296] to
>   Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/user/pingActor/pongActor#1725419686] was
>   not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be
>   turned off or adjusted with configuration settings
>   'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

**why the sender that sent the message prior to the crash is not available ? is there a way to overcome it ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/actors.html#initialization-via-prestart) states, the default behavior when an actor is restarted is to stop all of that actor's children. This is the reason that the message to `sender` after the restart goes to dead letters. You need to override the default behavior and set the initialization of the child (i.e., `PongActor`) in the `preStart()` hook. Also, remove the call to `super.postRestart(reason)`.

```
class PingActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import PingActor._

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    pongActor = Option(context.actorOf(PongActor.props, "pongActor"))
  }

  override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = {
    log.info("Don't stop the children")
    postStop()
  }

  override def postRestart(reason: Throwable): Unit = {
    log.info("RESTARTING")
  }

  var counter = 0
  var pongActor: Option[ActorRef] = None

  def receive = {
    case Initialize => 
      pongActor.foreach(_ ! PingMessage("ping"))
    case PongActor.PongMessage(text) =>
      ...
  } 
}
```

Making the above changes results in the following output:

```
In PongActor - received message: ping
In PingActor - received message: pong
In PongActor - received message: ping
In PingActor - received message: pong
In PongActor - received message: ping
Don't stop the children
RESTARTING
In PingActor - received message: pong
In PongActor - received message: ping
In PingActor - received message: pong
In PongActor - received message: ping
Don't stop the children
RESTARTING
In PingActor - received message: pong
In PongActor - received message: ping
In PingActor - received message: pong
In PongActor - received message: ping
Don't stop the children
RESTARTING
In PingActor - received message: pong
In PongActor - received message: ping
...
```

More information on restarting in addition to the first link is found [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/general/supervision.html#what-restarting-means).